# how to detect if any of the links of a list are active. and aply css class to the parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, selector

I want to check if any link of a parent is active (parents in my code id="menu-item-461" and id="menu-item-462") and then apply a extra class to the div with a .submenu class of that parent.

But here comes the tricky bit: the site should go to the link.

I got this far but now I'm stuck.

```
$(function(){
  $("#menu-item-461 a").onclick(function(){
    $("#menu-item-461 a").removeClass("selected")
    $(this).addClass("selected")
    return false;
  })
```

But this does only apply it to the current link. and doesn't follow the hyperlink. So how do I check if any of the links from a class are active? and then apply css class to the .submenu?

```html
<ul>
  <li id="menu-item-461" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category current-post-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-post-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-461">

    <a href="http://bertconinx.com/category/portriats/">portriats</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-473" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post current-menu-item menu-item-473">
        <a href="http://bertconinx.com/2019/08/12/non-profit-profit/" aria-current="page">Disarray Body</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-617" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-617">
        <a href="http://bertconinx.com/2019/09/16/girls/">#Girls</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li id="menu-item-462" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category current-post-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-post-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-461">

    <a href="http://bertconinx.com/category/portriats/">Item2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-412" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post current-menu-item menu-item-473">
        <a href="http://bertconinx.com/2019/08/12/non-profit-profit/" aria-current="page">object1</a></li>

      <li id="menu-item-619" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-617">
        <a href="http://bertconinx.com/2019/09/16/girls/">Object2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: onclick is not a jQuery function, you need .on("click",function(e) { }) and NOT return false if you want the link to work

Comment: You also likely want to use session or localStorage to persist the click

Comment: it should be something like this. I used this years a go. but now I'm changing it to a wordpress theme.

function expandingMenu(num) {
 var speed = 200;
 
 var item_title = $("#menu-item-461 a").eq(num).children(":first");
 var items = $(".submenu").eq(num).children().filter(function (index) { return index > 0; });
 
 /* hide items if not active */
 if (items.is(".active") === false) {
  items.hide();
 }

 /* add click functions + pointer to title */
 item_title.css({cursor:"pointer"}).toggle(
  function () {
   items.show(speed);
  }, function () {
   items.hide(speed);
  }

Comment: Please update your question instead of pasting unformatted code into a comment or using answer to post more information

Answer (score 0):

it should be something like this. 
I used this years a go. but now I'm changing it to a wordpress theme.

```js
function expandingMenu(num) {
 var speed = 200;
 
 var item_title = $("#menu-item-461 a").eq(num).children(":first");
 var items = $(".submenu").eq(num).children().filter(function (index) { return index > 0; });
 
 /* hide items if not active */
 if (items.is(".active") === false) {
  items.hide();
 }

 /* add click functions + pointer to title */
 item_title.css({cursor:"pointer"}).toggle(
  function () {
   items.show(speed);
  }, function () {
   items.hide(speed);
  }
 )
}
```